# Java : casting in clone() method

Tags: java

Last week in our java course we were introduced the Object class and some of its methods 
one of these methods was clone() and when our teacher explained us this method we were told
that every-time that we clone an an object we have to down-cast the returned object by clone()
because clone() returns an object of the Object type.

Therefore, I couldn't find a reason why would this method prefer to return a generic Object when it could easily get the type of the cloned object with another method like getClass()
and handle the down-casting automatically.

oh btw this is no homework it's just my personal curiosity that led me to ask this (my teacher could give me an precise answer so I decided to let him be for now :D )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the java.lang.Object base class signature for clone() returns Object. You can override the returned type on a subclassed method, but it's not really necessary anyway.  Since you already know the class that you're cloning, you can simply cast it to the class that you are cloning and things will be fine.

Rereading your question, I notice you ask why it doesn't just get the type of the cloned object and handle the down-casting automatically.  Internally it sort of is doing this already; it's really more that `clone()` is returning a specific object that's been upcast to `Object`, which all Java objects inherit from.  However, the compiler isn't about to change the type of the variable you're assigning `clone()`'s return value to.

Since you already know the class you're trying to get at, there isn't any reason you can't just cast it yourself.

Comment: I understand now, so it's just a way to avoid strange cases like the one you've described earlier :)

Comment: Java has covariant return types for overridden methods so you can indeed override the return type with a more specific type for `clone`. Also, in your example there is no problem in `someObject.clone()` returning something of (static) type A as if would if `A.clone()` was overridden to declare a more specific type.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz Regarding the `someObject.clone()` example, I realize that, but I wanted to keep the answer simple, as this was a 'homework' question.  Obviously the returned `B` can quite reasonably be cast to `A` - but it can also be quite reasonably cast to `Object`.  As far as covariance, in my experience Java compilers emit a warning (if not an outright error) if you try to override the return type; certainly it does that on `clone()` in any case.

Comment: There is not compiler warning, and there is no reason why there would be one.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz Oh, you're right, I just wrote a simple test app and it was just fine. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Just to muddle the waters more, `int[] a = new int[]{}.clone()` will compile fine - so obviously the compiler can do this sort of special-casing.

Comment: Probably depends a lot on the particular compiler and version and build settings.  I prefer to err on the side of explicitness and strict adherence, myself.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a result of many revisions and slightly strange design choices. For some reason the designers of Java decided that `clone` always returns something of type `Object`, while as you point out yourself the `getClass` method always returns something of type `Class<? extends A>` if the method is called on a class A.

The co-variant return types of Java allow you to override `clone` to have the correct return type, but standard practice is to just live with this short-coming and cast the object after calling `clone`.